# Kotlin declare nested array

Tags: list, arraylist, kotlin, nested, declare

How can nested lists be declared in Kotlin?
I'm looking for something in the form of:

```
var nestedList:List = [1,[2,[3,null,4]],[null],5]
```

so that I can flatten it later on (result should be nestedList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).

Comment: What is the data type that you expect this structure to have? Kotlin is a statically typed language, so you can either have an array (or list) where each element is also an array (or list), or an array (or list) where each element is a value.

Comment: so array or list?:)

Comment: Considering the problem I'm trying to solve, I would need an array where each element is also an array.

Comment: actually in this particular example Int and Array types are mixed. a single array contains either 1 and another array: `[1,[2,[3,null,4]],...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have nested arrays structure (for instance, `val array: Array<Array<out Int?>> = arrayOf(arrayOf(1), arrayOf(2), arrayOf(3, null, 4))`), you can just use `flatten` extension method:

```
println(array.flatten().filterNotNull())
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but is there a way so that I do not have to hard code the number of layers (in your example that being 2)?

Comment: pls man dont try at home and at work.

`inline fun <reified T> flatArray(array: Array<*>): Array<T> {
    var temp: Array<*> = arrayOf(*array)
    while (!temp.isEmpty() && temp[0] is Array<*>) {
        temp = flatLevel(temp)
    }
    val result: Array<T?> = arrayOfNulls(temp.size)
    for ((index, value) in temp.withIndex()) {
        result[index] = value as T
    }
    return result.asSequence().filterNot { it.isNull() }.toList().toTypedArray() as Array<T>
}`

Comment: `fun flatLevel(array: Array<*>): Array<*> {
    if (!array.isEmpty()) {
        val result = mutableListOf<Any?>()
        for (innerArray in array) {
            val castedArray = innerArray as Array<*>
            for (innerItem in castedArray) {
                result.add(innerItem)
            }
        }
        return result.toTypedArray()
    }
    return array
}`

Comment: I just did it because it was challenging. it is BETTER to find another solution which just won't result into this code. the best thing possible is to forbid variable deepness and use type-safe code

Answer (score 2):

All common collections can't maintain variable layers count, so with them you can make only something like Andrey Ilyunin wrote - `val array: Array<Array<out Int?>>`.

But I wrote class structure to help you with your goal. It is no another collection and you can't work with it like it is, but it can make any layers amount you want. It is totally generic, so you can put there not only `Int`.

First of all, we start with `NestedArrayItem` class, which represents single item or one more nested array:

```
class NestedArrayItem<T> {
    private val array: ArrayList<NestedArrayItem<T>>?
    private val singleItem: T?
    constructor(array: ArrayList<NestedArrayItem<T>>) {
        this.array = array
        singleItem = null
    }
    constructor(singleItem: T?) {
        this.singleItem = singleItem
        array = null
    }
    fun asSequence(): Sequence<T?> =
        array?.asSequence()?.flatMap { it.asSequence() } ?:
            sequenceOf(singleItem)
    override fun toString() =
        array?.joinToString(prefix = "[", postfix = "]") ?:
            singleItem?.toString() ?: "null"
}
```

Then class `NestedArray` that is just like top level container for all the layers:

```
class NestedArray<T> {
    private val array: ArrayList<NestedArrayItem<T>> = arrayListOf()

    fun add(value: T?) {
        array.add(NestedArrayItem(value))
    }

    fun addNested(nestedArray: NestedArray<T>) {
        array.add(NestedArrayItem(nestedArray.array))
    }

    fun flatten(): ArrayList<T?> = array.asSequence()
        .flatMap { it.asSequence() }
        .toCollection(arrayListOf())

    override fun toString() = array.joinToString(prefix = "[", postfix = "]")
}
```

And to make it easier to write values I additionally wrote builder class for that:

```
class NestedArrayBuilder<T> private constructor(private val result: NestedArray<T>){
    constructor(fillNestedBuilder: NestedArrayBuilder<T>.() -> Unit) : this(NestedArray()) {
        NestedArrayBuilder(result).apply(fillNestedBuilder)
    }
    fun add(value: T?): NestedArrayBuilder<T> {
        result.add(value)
        return this
    }
    fun addArray(fillNestedBuilder: NestedArrayBuilder<T>.() -> Unit): NestedArrayBuilder<T> {
        val nestedResult = NestedArray<T>()
        val nestedArray = NestedArrayBuilder(nestedResult).apply(fillNestedBuilder)
            .build()
        result.addNested(nestedArray)
        return this
    }

    fun build() = result
}
```

That's it! You can use it. I put here example how to use it:

```
val array = NestedArrayBuilder<Int> {
    add(1)
    addArray {
        add(2)
        addArray {
            add(3)
            add(null)
            add(4)
        }
    }
    addArray {
        add(null)
    }
    add(5)
}.build()
assertEquals("[1, [2, [3, null, 4]], [null], 5]", array.toString())
assertEquals(arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, null, 4, null, 5), array.flatten())
```